# How to remove a previous rectangle created with pygame.draw.rect and having a picture as background

Tags: python, pygame

Searching the solution to my problem, I saw that some persons encoutered the same problem as I have, and the solution was to display the background at the beggining of the loop, so we don't see previous position etc..
In my case the rectangle represents a health bar for a character in my Python game.
I tried `screen.blit(background, [0,0])` or even tried `pygame.display.flip()`, and that strangely does not solve the problem, I don't know what else to do.
Here is the part of my code :

```
import os
import pygame
pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((885,500))
backgroundgame = pygame.image.load(os.path.join(image, 'background.jpg'))

def display():
    screen.blit(backgroundgame, [0,0])
    pygame.display.update()

def health_bar(health_player, health_ennemy):
    screen.blit(backgroundgame, [0,0])
    pygame.draw.rect(background, health_player, (x, y-20, 65, 8))

palying = True
while playing:
    health_bar(health_player, health_ennemy)
    display()
```

I didn't put all my code, but actually the rectangle moves with the sprite, but can still see the preivous healthbar (rectangles), even updating the screen. There are not a single error running the script.

Comment: Sorry, now it's translated, the screen is the window you know, and background is the picture which is filling the whole window. If I print the rectangle on the screen, so it will be displayed under the background, so I have to print it on the background.

Comment: So basically I have to change `pygame.draw.rect(background, health_player, (x, y-20, 65, 8))` by `pygame.draw.rect(screen, health_player, (x, y-20, 65, 8))` ? It doesn't work, that's why I put the background instead, but for my sprites it works, I really don't know what's wrong.

Comment: Ok, I did it. It removes the background and now we can see all my sprites' movements. I think this command is needed, each time we go in a loop it refresh the screen, so we avoid seeing all the previous changes in general, maybe you want to see my whole script ? But I can't post it here because it's too long.

Comment: So do you still have a problem?

Comment: No, thank you. I tried to move `pygame.draw.rect(screen, health_player, (x, y-20, 65, 8))` in `display` function, after `screen.blit(backgroundgame, [0,0])`, it works, it also works if I put `screen.blit(backgroundjeu, [0,0])` in the loop `while playing`, but to make my code clearer, I would like to divide different parts of my game in dedicated functions. But apparently I couldn't.. So actually I moved `screen.blit(backgroundgame, [0,0])` at the end of the loop `while playing`, after calling function `health_bar`, and I moved all my code in `health_bar` function to display one.